# gsub() stripping characters

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove spaces from a string under specific situations:

- trailing spaces
- spaces preceding a vertical bar

This is working fine but if the input string contains characters beyond ASCII 128, these are also removed. I've tried converting the input string to UTF-8 but this hasn't solved the problem.

The code:

```
column_utf8 <- iconv(inData$column, from="ISO-8859-1", to="UTF-8")
column_utf8_notrailing <- gsub("\\s+$", "", column_utf8)
column_utf8_notrailing_noembedded <- gsub("\\s+\\|", "\\|", column_utf8_notrailing)
outData <- data.frame(column_utf8, column_utf8_notrailing_noembedded)
```

However, looking at an abstract of the "before" and "after" values in *outData*:

**column_utf8**

| Char | ASCII |
| --- | --- |
| E | 69 |
| X | 88 |
| T | 84 |
| *non-printing* | 160 |
| *space* | 32 |
| | | 124 |

**column_utf8_notrailing_noembedded**

| Char | ASCII |
| --- | --- |
| E | 69 |
| X | 88 |
| T | 84 |
| | | 124 |

As expected, the *space* before the vertical bar has been removed, but so has the *non-printing* character (ASCII 160).

I tried adding "useBytes=TRUE" to the gsub() but this returned ASCII 194 in the place where ASCII 160 had previously been located!

Can anyone advise how to prevent the removal of this non-printing character? Thanks.

Comment: Converting from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8 turns the single non-breaking space character from the byte `0xa0` (160) to _two_ bytes; `0xc2 0xa0` (194 160), which is where your 194 is coming from. Your code works perfectly well for me if the string encoding is kept as latin1 (ISO-8859-1)

Comment: Hi Allan. That's really odd since I only added the conversion as I was getting issues. With the updated code:


`column_notrailing <- gsub("\\s+$", "", inData$column)
column_notrailing_noembedded <- gsub("\\s+\\|", "\\|", column_notrailing)
outData <- data.frame(inData$column, column_notrailing_noembedded)`

Comment: **column** ends with:

E - 69
X - 88
T - 84
? - 63
_space_ - 32
| - 124

**column notrailing noembedded** ends with:

E - 69
X - 88
T - 84
? - 63
? - 63
| - 124

So the _non-printing_ character has been converted to a standard question mark (ASCII 63) and in the updated version, it has been duplicated!

Comment: I think I've solved it. I reverted to the original, non-UTF-8 code, but instead of using \s I just used a space character. I only realised afterwards that character 160 is a non-breaking space and was being included in the \s. However specifying the space as a space (ASCII 32), it works as required.

Comment: BTW - Any ideas why `gsub(" +$", "", inData$column)` works but `gsub("\040+$", "", inData$column)` doesn't? The latter makes it more obvious that I only want to remove _normal_ spaces whereas the former can miss the space character.

Comment: How can the former miss the space character?

Comment: Sorry. I meant "someone reading the code could miss the space character"